# Determine if table cell is visible in viewport

Tags: html, viewport

I am very new to frontend. Suppose we have a table in html page. Now I want to create a function. In that function, I will pass rowId and columnId. And that function will check if that cell is visible in viewport or not. If not then it will scroll the table left/right or up/down.

I am not sure how to check if any cell is visible in viewport or not? Can anyone help here.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: [Hundreds of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=element+visible+in+viewport+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan sure, I will try out above examples and update my question accordingly.